# For what values of p the series is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(n\log(n))^p}$$

I use Cauchy's condensation criterion but this give the next series:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(n\log(2))^p}$$

$\log(2)^p$ is a constant, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I think you used the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) wrong.

Comment: Compare to $\sum_{n \ge 2} n^{-p}$

Comment: @vonbrand like this: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know the basics. If $p\gt 1$ then $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges. So by comparison our series does.

The series $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges by the integral test, or Cauchy Condensation. So for $p=1$ our series diverges.

If $p\lt 1$, then, at least for $n\ge 3$, the $n$-th term is bigger than $\frac{1}{n\log n}$, so by comparison we have divergence.

**Remark:** Your calculation was nearly finished. Cauchy Condensation gave you that our series converges if and only if $\sum k\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges, where $k$ was an explicit constant. The constant does not affect convergence, and you know for which $p$ $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges.